# Can't install `environs` with pip on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, pip

When I try to install `environs` 4.1.0 suing:

```
pip3 install environs==4.1.0
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
```

Running `sudo apt update` doesn't change anything. I also tried to do
`sudo apt install environs` and `sudo apt install environs==4.1.0`
but it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package environs
```

`python3 -m pip install environs==4.1.0` outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import ( 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
  ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/__init__.py)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Next time try searching the error (last line): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823964/importerror-cannot-import-name-sysconfig-from-distutils-usr-lib-python3-8

Comment: I searched it in many sites but nothing of that hasn't work yet

Comment: So "sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils" from my link didn't work for your "python3 -m pip install environs==4.1.0"?